# Famous People Known By 3 Names

Tags: knowledge

Famous People Known By 3 Names :

> 2 CFV  - 6,9,7 - female
>   14 MDS - 4,6,6 - female
>   16 JSP  - 5,6,6 - female

Comment: Why [tag:story]? Isn't this more [tag:trivia]?

Answer (score 1):

2 CFV  - 6,9,7 - female

> [Cheryl Fernandez-Versini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheryl_(entertainer))

14 MDS - 4,6,6 - female

> [Mary Decker Slaney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Decker)

16 JSP  - 5,6,6 - female

> [Janet Street-Porter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janet_Street-Porter), as found by JonMark Perry

Though, I'm not quite sure what the numbers on the front represent here..

Comment: I think those numbers indicate these three were part of a larger list, and the OP knew the others.

Answer (score 0):

**16 JSP  - 5,6,6 - female**

> [Janet Street-Porter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janet_Street-Porter)